# Как создавать Bundles в Symfony 4?

Tags: symfony

Как в Symfony 4 создать бандл для повторного использования? В best practices по Symfony 4 не рекомендуют создавать бандлы внутри своего приложения, а команда generate:bundle убрана из консоли

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Особо ничего не поменялось. Сделали более общий подход для использования PHP библиотек общего пользования и Symfony бандлов. Сейчас весь менеджмент пакетов для Symfony осуществляется с помощью Symfony Flex, которая позволяет писать рецепты по установке бандлов. Инструкцию можно найти здесь: https://github.com/symfony/recipes/blob/master/README.rst.

То есть если у вас нет зависимостей от других бандлов и конфигураций контейнера зависимостей, то можно сделать библиотеку, которая будет пригодна не только для использования с Symfony, но и в остальном PHP-мире, просто для Symfony описать рецепт, который эту библиотеку настроит нормально в рамках Symfony проекта.

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем так. Бандлы убрали отчасти из-за того, что никто ими пользоваться-то и не умел. Хочешь делать бандл - никто тебе не мешает, просто заведи малюсенькую строчку в composer.json для autoload.
Но другой вопрос, готов ли ты организовывать логику так, чтобы твой бандл ни в коем случае не был связан c другими бандлами, включая App? Если нет или не понял зачем - тебе не нужен дополнительный бандл. Пока я видел только 1 кейс, когда реально нужен отдельный бандл - возможность вынести этот бандл после в отдельное приложение, то бишь сделать SOA. Т.е. сначала делается отдельное "под-приложение" в основном монолитном приложении, которая коммуницирует с App по `amqp` и прочее, а после это уже без проблем можно вынести в отдельный репозиторий, в отдельный проект для деплоя и завести на него отдельную команду разработчиков например.